# SQL Return All Combinations of Two Columns and Their Number of Occurences

Tags: sql, join, outer-join

I'm trying to do something in SQL that maybe I can't do.  I have a single table with this type of data (synthetic data shown):

```
columnn1 | column2 | ...
------------------------
    A    |    1    |
    B    |    1    |
    C    |    2    |
    A    |    2    |
    D    |    3    |
    A    |    1    |
    B    |    1    |
```

What I'd like to get back is something that both:

1. Computes all combinations (e.g., cross join), and
2. Also includes the number of times the combinations occur.

I know how to do the combinations with a simple CROSS JOIN.  I can also get the number of combinations with a simple GROUP BY clause.  However, is there a way to efficiently combine these into a single query?  What I want to try to avoid is generating and saving an intermediate table.  The output I'd like looks like this:

```
columnn1 | column2 | count
---------------------------
    A    |    1    |   2
    A    |    2    |   1
    A    |    3    |   0 (or null)
    B    |    1    |   2
    B    |    2    |   0 (or null)
    B    |    3    |   0 (or null)
    C    |    1    |   0 (or null)
    C    |    2    |   1
    C    |    3    |   0 (or null)
    D    |    1    |   0 (or null)
    D    |    2    |   0 (or null)
    D    |    3    |   1
```

I don't really care if the counts are zero (preferred) or nullls.  I also don't care about the sorting order of the columns.  I've done some searching and can't seem to find a way to do this without generating and saving an intermediate table.  I'm probably just overlooking something silly though.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming none of the values in the table are `NULL`, you can take the following strategy.  Use `cross join` to get all the combinations of the two columns -- even combinations that are not in the data.

Then use `left join` and `group by` to get the counts you are looking for:

```
select c1.col1, c2.col2, count(t.col1)
from (select distinct col1 from table) c1 cross join
     (select distinct col2 from table) c2 left join
     table t
     on t.col1 = c1.col1 and t.col2 = c2.col2
group by c1.col1, c2.col2;
```

Handling `NULL` values is pretty easy, but it requires a bit more logic.

Comment: That's it!  Thanks!  I had some issues with my left join which was preventing me from getting the correct answer.  Much appreciated!